# Tkinter ComboBox generado automatico, como cambiarle el estado

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, combobox

**De antemano, muchas gracias**

No he logrado encontrar la forma en la que podría cambiarle el estado a un ComboBox generado, dado que se genera para ahorrar codigo mediante una funcion ya definida, como es así, el ComboBox generado no tendría una identificación clara, para usar.

```
ComboBox['state'] = 'normal'
```

Lo anterior no funciona, asi como tampoco.

```
Hola = ComboBox(frame, algoCombo, normalFont, 5, AlgoFuncion, 1, 'W', algoValues,  1, 1)
Hola['state'] = 'normal'
```

El codigo completo, lo dejo a continuación.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def AlgoFuncion(*args):
    pass

def ComboBox(frame, variable, font, width, function, cspan, sticky, values, x, y):
    ComboBox = ttk.Combobox(frame, textvariable = variable, width = width, font = font)
    ComboBox['values'] = values
    ComboBox['state'] = 'readonly'
    ComboBox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', function)
    ComboBox.grid(columnspan = cspan, sticky = sticky, column = x, row = y)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(bg = 'black')
    root.title('TEST')
    normalFont = 'Times 11'

    frame = tk.Frame(root, bg = '#FFFFFF')
    frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

    algoCombo = tk.StringVar()
    algoValues = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
    ComboBox(frame, algoCombo, normalFont, 5, AlgoFuncion, 1, 'W', algoValues,  1, 1)

    while True:
        root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Dado que usare muchos combobox, entre otras cosas, consideré como buena opcion el crear una funcion que se encargara de ello, llamandola cuando sea necesario y poder asi no solo ahorrar tiempo, si no dejar un poco mas legible el codigo, soy bastante novato en esto y por ello acudo a ustedes. Pero ocurre que en ciertas ocasiones deberé cambiar el estado de los combobox y no he logrado descifrar como hacerlo, cuando estos son creados mediante la funcion propia.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda prestada.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que veo es que estas intentando acceder a las propiedades del objeto `ComboBox` del modulo `ComboBox` que está dentro de la función `ComboBox`, pero en realidad estás intentando cambiar la propiedad 'state' de la función `ComboBox` que no tiene ninguna porque no es posible. Te recomiendo que nunca reutilices nombres o sufrirás terribles pesadillas y un gatito morirá.

Prueba a devolver el objeto creado en la función y a asignarlo a una etiqueta

```
def ComboBox(..):
    ComboBox = ttk.ComboBox(...)
    ...
    return ComboBox

....

algoValues = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
combo_1 = ComboBox(frame, algoCombo, normalFont, 5, AlgoFuncion, 1, 'W', algoValues,  1, 1)

....
combo_1['state'] = 'normal'      <--- Aquí deberías poder cambiar el atributo del objeto combo_1 que hereda todo del objeto padre ComboBox que hereda del objeto ttk.Combobox que has declarado en la funcion ComboBox
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, eso ha resuelto por completo mi problema.

Comment: De nada. Si te ha resuelto pulsa en aceptar respuesta para darla por cerrada. Un saludo